# Read Data using SocketIo on NodeJS side?

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Many tutorials, especially those "chat apps", show you how to use NodeJS as your SocketIO server and then you implement a JS script in an HTML page as the client.

What I want to know is how can I connect to a websocket via NodeJS?

For example, I have this page which has a websocket running: https://i.imgur.com/hPGmzWv.png

Instead of connecting to this websocket through this page, I would like to read (and hopefully save) the data through NodeJS.

How could I do that with SocketIO?

Answer (score 0):

Socket.IO actually isn't a Web Socket client, strictly speaking.  It's a layer on top, that can use several transports.  Web Sockets is one of those transports, but as is long-polling AJAX and other methods.

If you want to connect to a Web Socket server, you need a Web Socket client library.  My go-to for this is [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws).  From their example documentation:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const ws = new WebSocket('ws://www.host.com/path');
 
ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send('something');
});
 
ws.on('message', function incoming(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

Comment: Very interesting! I guess i misunderstood the role of SocketIO and ws. Thanks! So for example, if I wanted to save the content of a stream (lets say audio was being played through this socket), wouldnt this work? https://pastebin.com/8Auixdpf (I feel it should but trying to open it does not work, it looks like the bytes are increasing though)

Comment: @Robert Possibly, but I actually suspect the source stream is messed up.  The developer tools in your browser shouldn't try to show that binary data as text, so they're probably sending MP3 binary data as text... which is the wrong thing to do.  That's probably messing up the encoding on the incoming message, and it's getting written to the file incorrectly.  That's just a hunch though...  no way to know for sure without actually seeing it.